# How to write Regex on last matching line then do another match then return the some value in log file?

Tags: regex, string, search

I need a help on REGEX I have a log file and will populate the log information.

I need to find the last occurrence of the some string and in the same line i need to get a value of the some string.

Below are the conditions :

1. It is runtime log file I need to find **last match in the log file** (means take latest match it will have lot of same entries.
2. Need to find a last line which has a text Tomcat - Deploy A New Application Simple Web App
3. In the same line where the text was found find the entry  result=Step Result: true ( This search should be done if the step2 text match is found)

4.Then return the step result value this case true.

I used below regex.
Deploy A New Application Simple Web App(.*)Step Result: (\w+)

Need a help on finding last entry of this and return only Step Result Value.

Example : ABCD.log

> 2017-09-21 22:47:37,381 [job-426106-jobServer-426106-3:Tomcat - Deploy
>   A New Application Simple Web App(P81.F2842.E2849.E2845)] DEBUG
>   (com.nolio.nimi.appmsg.durability.DurableCommunicationApi:155) - Got
>   new message:
>   INBAHRLP01735_150556657499340:payload=[ID:8444fce1d80a400_7f7@INBAHRLP01735,
>   from:INBAHRLP01735,
>   to:executionLog__426106_INBAHRLP01735@es_INBAHRLP01735-
>   StepExecutionEventDto [result=Step Result: true - Deploy an web
>   application [simple-web-app] successfully., hostIp=INBAHRLP01735,
>   jobId=426106, envServerId=426106, timestamp=Thu Sep 21 22:47:37 IST
>   2017, state=FINISHED, stepId=P81.F2842.E2849.E2845, stepTitle=Tomcat -
>   Deploy A New Application Simple Web App, startDate=Thu Sep 21 22:47:22
>   IST 2017, stopDate=Thu Sep 21 22:47:37 IST 2017, eventCounter=4264]]
>   2017-09-21 22:48:37,381 [job-426106-jobServer-426106-3:Tomcat - Deploy
>   A New Application Simple Web App(P81.F2842.E2849.E2845)] DEBUG
>   (com.nolio.nimi.appmsg.durability.DurableCommunicationApi:155) - Got
>   new message:
>   INBAHRLP01735_150556657499340:payload=[ID:8444fce1d80a400_7f7@INBAHRLP01735,
>   from:INBAHRLP01735,
>   to:executionLog__426106_INBAHRLP01735@es_INBAHRLP01735-
>   StepExecutionEventDto [**result=Step Result: true** - Deploy an web
>   application [simple-web-app] successfully., hostIp=INBAHRLP01735,
>   jobId=426106, envServerId=426106, timestamp=Thu Sep 21 22:47:37 IST
>   2017, state=FINISHED, stepId=P81.F2842.E2849.E2845, stepTitle=Tomcat -
>   Deploy A New Application Simple Web App, startDate=Thu Sep 21 22:48:22
>   IST 2017, stopDate=Thu Sep 21 22:48:37 IST 2017, eventCounter=4264]]

Comment: Hi, please take a tour of how to use stack and also about the formatting of questions and answer. Formatting helps other user understand your point very clearly.

Comment: Add `.*` at the pattern start. Make sure . can match a linebreak with the appropriate modifier for your engine or use `[\s\S]` instead.

Comment: Hi Wiktor,  
       
      Thank you for the reply. I could able to match all the string found.  Please find the link below for the details
  [Screenshot link](https://github.com/mohansgithub/DevOps/blob/master/Tools/Regex.JPG)          now problem is i am not able to get only last matched string.

Comment: I mean to say I manage to find last entry in this example i can match the exact string what i want